# Changing src attribute of img using a svg generator on the server does not trigger a HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

This is my simple situation:

```
$('#imgId').attr('src', '/genImage');
```

This is part of an onclick handler. genImage is a node script that generates SVG dynamically. The HTML for the element is:

```
<img id="imgId" src="/genImage"></img>
```

When the page loads initially, genImage does its work and the image is shown. The onclick handler fails to make the change. Chrome shows that a request is not made at all. My headers sent with the image are:

```
 Content-Type:  image/svg+xml
 Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
 Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0, false 
 Last-Modified: October 21, 2009 00:00:00 GMT
```

The issue really is that '/genCaptcha' is NOT a file in the true sense. It is a section in the server code that generates image and associated headers. It works when the page is initially loaded. I THINK IT IS NOT RELOADED BECAUSE THE SRC VALUE HAS NOT CHANGED AND THEREFORE JQUERY DOES NOT INITIATE A FRESH REQUEST. Is that the case? How to handle this situation? I can possibly send some dummy randomly generated parameters to the request to make it a unique URl but is there a better way to force a request even when the src value is the same as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cache's can be a pain, just when you think you've forced a reload, some browser comes along and does things different (hello IE) ... just do something like

```
$('#imgId').attr('src', '/genImage?random=' + Math.random());
```

Comment: As noted by me, I am aware of this solution and was wondering if  "there [is] a better way to force a request even when the src value is the same as before?" Anyhow, I am going ahead with this solution. Seems there is no other alternative and this is sure to beat all cache issues as you pointed out.

Comment: I seriously did not read the bit about the dummy parameters :p Once I hit the CAPS text I stopped reading :D